# How do I get the height of a dynamically sized section header in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`, it uses a custom `UIView` as the section header view. Code like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
  return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ECStartTableHeaderView") as! ECStartTableHeaderView
  return headerView
}
```

I have `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for the height on the header. I need to find out what this height is in my code. How can I get this header height?

Comment: Maybe `tableView.headerView(forSection: 0)?.height`? Just not sure where you want to get the height

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to ensure your header layout finished first, so you can get actual height.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let height = view.frame.height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take out the Height of the Header View Just Like.

```
if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
   height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
}
```